# ImageView with StateListDrawable not working

Tags: android, imageview, statelistdrawable

This seems so simple, but it is just not working.  The ImageView should change bitmaps when it is checked, but instead it always shows the unchecked image:

```
public void addImage()
{
  ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
  m_draw = new StateListDrawable();

  m_draw.addState(android.util.StateSet.WILD_CARD, m_bitmapUnchecked);
  m_draw.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_checked }, m_bitmapChecked);

  imageView.setImageDrawable(m_draw);

  this.addView(imageView);
}

public void onClick(View v)
{
  m_draw.setState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_checked });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first matching state is the one which will be set. You should put WILD_CARD as the last state.